# Can my email recipient see all previous emails in the thread if they were not initially included, or do they just see what they're included in?

Tags: email, privacy, email-etiquette

Background: My recruiter forwarded me his email thread with a prospective employer.

Question: Can everyone that was a part of this thread from the onset be able to see my correspondence with the prospective employer?

Clarification: Some past recipients were no longer included in the thread my recruiter forwarded to me. I copied my recruiter in my first email (response to my recruiter) and directed my email to the prospective employer.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey There, this feels more like a technical question regarding emails, rather than asking on how to navigate the workplace as stated in the [help/dont-ask]. What other's can see greatly depends on how you forward the email, your personal settings, if you manually deleted or not previous exchanges, etc... by merely going to your "sent" tab you could see the email in question and answer yourself... have you checked that?

Comment: The title and the body seem to be asking different things. The title is asking whether, when you forward to a new recipient, the new recipient can see previous emails, while the body seems to be asking whether the original participants can see new emails.

Comment: Hello, I see what you mean on both fronts. Apologies, I didn't know technical questions weren't part of the Workplace Stack Exchange. I'll keep it to work place questions in the future.  Email Thread visibility Quest: FYI, I dug around my gmail settings and I interpret the explanation to say that people in the thread can see the whole thread regardless of where they are part of the thread - beginning or last recipient it was forwarded to. I like your site. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email is *only* what you see in your email client. There is *no* way to see an email that the email is in response to.

Email clients do a lot of stuff to help you keep track of previous email though, most notably keep track of other email you have gotten and include the replied to email in any of your replies.

But they cannot do anything with mail that they haven't received.

In short, no, *only* the people you sent the mail to get to know *anything* about the mail you sent.

Comment: An email also consists of BCC-Recipients which you can't see

Comment: @FooTheBar I'd argue you can see bcc recipient if there are any in your email. It's just that those are only in the mail you send. The mail received by any recipient is a different email, which doesn't include bcc. :) My first draft had more detail, but for The Workplace I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're replying to a forwarded email then only those listed as recipients along with you will see it. It's not the same email thread, it's a forwarded copy of it.